# Limit scrape to X amount of characters + other specifications with RegEx

Tags: php, mysql, regex

You can all skip this background-info, though its helpful.

**BACKGROUND**

I own a website that indexes all psychologists of Denmark. 
My site provides contact information for all the clinics as well as user ratings.

I'm currently listing 12.000 Psychologists, of which about 6.000 have a website. About 1000 of the Psychologists have visited my website, and filled out their profile with additional "Descriptive" info (such as opening hours, prices, etc.)

I'm attempting to automatically scrape (with PHP and RegEx) the sites of those who haven't provided details to my community, for informative reasons.

I went through about a good random 150 of the websites, and concluded that more than 85 % af them, have valuable text proceeding the word 'Velkommen' (=welcome, in Denish). PRECIOUS!

**THE QUESTIONS**

**#1**

How do I specificy in my script, that I'd only like to grab approx. 360 characters, and nothing more. Ofc. this should be preceeding (and including) the word Velkommen. Also, the script shouldn't be case sensitive (though Velkommen is usually spelled with a capital V, it can pop up in another sentence.)

Also, it should the last occuring 'velkommen' on the whole frontpage, since it sometimes occurs as a Menu/Navigation option, which would suck, since i'd then grab the navigation options.

**#2**

Currently, my script saves info in multiple-arrays, and then in the database.

Not sure how I should even go about this. What would be optimal for SEO;

1. Save the scraped text in a MySQL and display that every time.
2. Render the same 360-characters-text every time [that follows 'Velkommen']
3. Render random 360-characters-text from the sites, each time someone views a specific Psychologist on my site.

Here's an example site and my current script:

```
$web = "http://www.psykologdorthelau.dk/";
$website = file_get_contents ($web);

preg_match_all("/velkommen.+?/sim", $website, $information);

//THIS SHOULD SPECIFICY THE VERY LAST 'VELKOMMEN' - it doesn't, I know :(
for($i = 0; $i < count($information[0]); $i++){

preg_match_all("/Velkommen (.+?)\"/sim", $information[0][$i], $text, PREG_SET_ORDER);

$psychologist[$i]['text'] = mysql_real_escape_string($text[0][1]);
}
```

Thank you to anyone who can solve this puzzle, from the wonderful country of Denmark.

Comment: I'm mobile at the moment so can't test. I suspect using a character limit instead of the + e.g [1,360]. Then add a .* outside the capture group before the quote. You may have to play with greedy settings to get it to get the most it can  upto the 360

Comment: Elaboration and code would be needed for that.

Comment: You've got two problems now.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
<?php

$web = "http://www.psykologdorthelau.dk/";
$website = file_get_contents ($web);

// TRY TO FIND ALL OF THE MATCHES
preg_match_all('/velkommen.{1,351}/ims', $website, $matches);

// PULL OUT THE LAST ITEM FROM THE `$matches`
$last_velkommen = array_pop($matches[0]);
```

Comment: I cannot even begin to express how helpful this was. It's exactly what I was looking for, I just tested it. quixrick, you rock.

Comment: How can I specify to grab ANY text, even if velkommens doesnt appear on the page?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean? If you want to grab all the text, you don't need REGEX at all; Just use what's in `$website`. In REGEX, the dot `.` means any character (except newline), which is what I am doing above. (We are including newlines with the `ms` pattern modifiers.) I am saying that there can be any character appearing after 'velkommen', 1 to 351 times (counting in the 9 characters in 'velkommen' = 360). So if you wanted any number of characters, you can take off the `{1,351}` and put in an asterisk `*`. `.` along with the `*` means any character appearing zero or more times.